# Why is there a reduction to REF to find the characteristic polynomial of a 4x4 matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, characteristic-polynomial

I'm asked to find the characteristic polynomial of the matrix: $A = \small\begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
2 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 4\\
\end{pmatrix}$. I've gotten $$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
p_A(t) &= \det (A-tI)\\ 
&= det \small\begin{pmatrix}
2-t & 2 & 0 & 0\\
2 & 2-t & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2-t & 2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 4-t\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{split}
\end{equation}$$

However, the mistake I seem to make comes from my evaluation of $det \small\begin{pmatrix}
2-t & 2 & 0 & 0\\
2 & 2-t & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2-t & 2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 4-t\\
\end{pmatrix}$.

My way of evaluating is:
$$\begin{equation} \begin{split}
det \small\begin{pmatrix}
2-t & 2 & 0 & 0\\
2 & 2-t & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2-t & 2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 4-t\\
\end{pmatrix} &= (2-t)(2-t)(2-t)(4-t) - 0\\
&=(2-t)^3(4-t).
\end{split} \end{equation}$$

When I use an eigenvalue calculator to check my polynomial, I see $p_A(t) = (4-t)^2(2-t)t$. The step-by-step solution says to find the determinant of $A-tI$ you have to reduce $A-tI$ to REF. My question is: Why do we have to reduce $A-tI$ to its REF?

Comment: the determinant is the product of the determinants of the blocks: you should have gotten $$   ((2-t)^2 - 4 )(2-t)(4-t) $$

Comment: @WillJagy But under the Laplase Expansion, shouldn't it be $(2-t)(2-t)(2-t)(4-t)+(2)(0)(2)(0)+(0)(0)(0)(0)+(0)(2)(0)(0)-(4-t)(0)(2-t)(0)-(0)(2)(2)(2)-(0)(2-t)(0)(2-t)-(0)(0)(0)(0)=(2-t)(2-t)(2-t)(4-t)+0=(4-t)(2-t)^3$?

Comment: no matter what you think is going on, one of the eigenvalues is zero, eigenvector $(1,-1,0,0)^T \; \; , \; \; $  where the T means transpose, so a column vector is intended

Comment: @WillJagy What's the reason we don't use the typical Laplase Expansion? Obviously can't for A since it's determinant is 0.

Answer (score 1):

For an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ the best formula to use is $$\det(\lambda I-A))=\lambda^n+\sum_{i=1}^n \beta_i\lambda^{n-i} $$ where $\beta_i=(-1)^i$ sum of principal minors of order $i$. Note that since $n=4$, $$\det(A-\lambda I)=(-1)^4 \det(\lambda I-A)=\det(\lambda I-A)$$ $$\beta_1=-\text {trace} A=-(2+2+2+4)=-10,$$ $$\beta_2=0+4+8+4+8+8=32$$
$$\beta_3=-(16+16+0+0)=-32$$ $$\beta_4=\det A=\text { by generalized Laplace expansion on rows 1&2 }=0 \times 8=0.$$ 
$$\det(A-\lambda I=\det(\lambda I-A)=\lambda^4-10\lambda^3+32\lambda^2-32\lambda.$$